# MongoDB - Erro ao executar find geoespacial $near

Tags: mongodb

Tenho uma coleção com os seguintes documentos.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c6bb6b492647b15f80038a1"),
    "loc" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordenadas" : [ 
            -41.104658, 
            -20.963387
        ]
    }
}
```

Estou executando o find:

```
db.tblfrota.find( 
   { loc : {
        $near :  { 
           $geometry :  { 
              type  :  "Point" , 
              coordenadas  :  [  parseFloat(-41.81064615) ,  parseFloat(-22.39813884)  ] 
           }, 
           $maxDistance :  5000 
        } 
   } 
   }
)
```

**Tenho os índices:**

```
[
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_"
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "loc.coordenadas" : "2dsphere"
        },
        "name" : "coord_3d", 
        "2dsphereIndexVersion" : 3
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "coordenadas" : "2d"
        },
        "name" : "coordenadas_2d"

    }
]
```

**Está retornando o erro :**

> Error: error: {   "ok" : 0,   "errmsg" : "invalid point in geo near
>   query $geometry argument: { type: \"Point\", coordenadas: [
>   -41.81064615, -22.39813884 ] }  Point must be an array or object",    "code" : 2,     "codeName" : "BadValue" }

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido: o erro era na sintaxe.

db.tblfrota.find( 
   { loc.coordenadas: {
        $near :  { 
           $geometry :  { 
              type  :  "Point" , 
              coordinates:  [  parseFloat(-41.81064615) ,  parseFloat(-22.39813884)  ] 
           }, 
           $maxDistance :  5000 
        } 
   } 
   }
)